# Transform data in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I need to transform data from server format to format for my UI library. But I can't completely understand how I should do this.

Name in new object is a field in object from server except "time"
And add "time" value for each fields
Need to transform this:

```
[
    {
        battery_charge: 0 
        battery_discharge: 0 
        consumption: 404    
        grid_backflow: 0    
        grid_consumption: 3     
        pv_generation: -7   
        time: "2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00" 
    }
    {
        battery_charge: 0   
        battery_discharge: 0    
        consumption: 404    
        grid_backflow: 0        
        grid_consumption: 3         
        pv_generation: -7       
        time: "2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00" 
    }
]
```

to this:

```
[
    {
        name: ‘Battery Charge’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
    {
        name: ‘Battery discharge’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
    {
        name: ‘Consumption’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
    {
        name: ‘Grid backflow’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
    {
        name: ‘Grid consumption’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
    {
        name: ‘Pv generation’
        data: [
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            { time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00', value: 3 }
            ]
    }
]
```

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: I should mention that I didn't write the code because I don't understand how to do it

Comment: @OlehStrokan  check my answer

Comment: @programoholic thank you!

Comment: @OlehStrokan accept if it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by first transforming into this format:

```js
{
  battery_charge: [
    {time: "2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00", value: 0},
    {time: "2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00", value: 0}
  ],
  battery_discharge: [ /*...*/ ],
  /* ... */
}
```

, which is a very common pattern and well-established.  Then we can map the entries of this into your `name / data` format.

We do the first conversion with a double-`reduce`, and the whole thing might look like this:

```js
const reformat = (data) =>
  Object .entries (data .reduce (
    (a, {time, ...rest}) => Object .entries (rest) .reduce (
      (a, [key, value]) => ((a [key] = [... (a [key] || []), {time, value}]), a)
      , a
    ), {}
  )) .map (([name, data]) => ({name, data}))

const data = [{battery_charge: 0, battery_discharge: 0, consumption: 404, grid_backflow: 0, grid_consumption: 3, pv_generation: -7, time: "2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00"}, {battery_charge: 0, battery_discharge: 0, consumption: 404, grid_backflow: 0, grid_consumption: 3, pv_generation: -7, time: "2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00"}]

console .log (reformat (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Tnank you a lot! This code much shorter what i already have!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way to achieve it :

```js
const data = [
  {
    battery_charge: 0,
    battery_discharge: 0,
    consumption: 404,
    grid_backflow: 0,
    grid_consumption: 3,
    pv_generation: -7,
    time: '2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00',
  },
  {
    battery_charge: 0,
    battery_discharge: 0,
    consumption: 404,
    grid_backflow: 0,
    grid_consumption: 3,
    pv_generation: -7,
    time: '2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00',
  },
];
const IGNORE_KEY_MAP = {
  time: 1,
};
function transformData(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return [];
  let dataMap = new Map();
  const keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    for (let key of keys) {
      if (!IGNORE_KEY_MAP[key]) {
        let mapValue = dataMap.get(key);
        if (mapValue) {
          let newData = [...mapValue, getInsertableData(item, key)];
          dataMap.set(key, newData);
        } else {
          dataMap.set(key, [getInsertableData(item, key)]);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  let result = [];
  dataMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    const obj = {
      name: key,
      data: value,
    };
    result.push(obj);
  });
  return result;
}
function getInsertableData(data, key) {
  return {
    time: data.time,
    value: data[key],
  };
}

console.log(transformData(data))
```

Interactive link : [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-v8twok?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks for your short code example!

Answer (score 0):

Some simple code.

```js
const
    data = [{ battery_charge: 0, battery_discharge: 0, consumption: 404, grid_backflow: 0, grid_consumption: 3, pv_generation: -7, time: "2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00" }, { battery_charge: 0, battery_discharge: 0, consumption: 404, grid_backflow: 0, grid_consumption: 3, pv_generation: -7, time: "2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { time, ...o }) => {
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([name, value]) => (r[name] ??= { name, data: [] }).data.push({ time, value }));
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your short code example. Just question: what does this operator mean: ??=.                            in .forEach line. I can't find this operator on internet

Comment: it is the [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator.

Comment: Thank you! Will go to documentation!)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var keys = {
    battery_charge: "Battery Charge",
    battery_discharge: "Battery discharge",
    consumption: "Consumption",
    grid_backflow: "Grid backflow",
    grid_consumption: "Grid consumption",
    pv_generation: "Pv generation",
  };

  var data = [
    {
      battery_charge: 0,
      battery_discharge: 0,
      consumption: 404,
      grid_backflow: 0,
      grid_consumption: 3,
      pv_generation: -7,
      time: "2019-02-25T00:00:00+00:00",
    },
    {
      battery_charge: 0,
      battery_discharge: 0,
      consumption: 404,
      grid_backflow: 0,
      grid_consumption: 3,
      pv_generation: -7,
      time: "2019-02-25T10:00:00+00:00",
    },
  ];

  var formatted = [];

  data.map((k) => {
    Object.keys(keys).map((x) => {
      if (!formatted.some((f) => f.key == x)) {
        formatted.push({
          title: keys[x],
          key: x,
          data: [],
        });
      }

      if (
        formatted.some(
          (y) => y.data.some((f) => f.time == k.time) && y.key == x
        )
      ) {
        var index = formatted.findIndex(
          (y) => y.data.some((f) => f.time == k.time) && y.key == x
        );
        var dataIndex = formatted[index].data.findIndex(
          (f) => f.time == k.time
        );
        formatted[index].data[dataIndex].value += k[x];
      } else {
        var index = formatted.findIndex((k) => k.key == x);
        formatted[index].data.push({ value: k[x], time: k.time });
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!